# Problems with declaring multiple functions

Tags: r

I'm designing a prime test on R. I came up with a function that utilizes another function to test whether a number is prime or not, but one of them is not being recognized

I took a function to generate the Pascal Triangle from another thread and declared it at the top, then created my secondary function.

```
ptest <- function(h) {
  for(i in h){
    x <- c(pascalTriangle(h)[h+1])
  } if(x%%h=0) {
    print(paste(h, "is a prime"))
  } else {
    print(paste(h, "is not a prime"))
  }
}
```

I expected this function to subset the Pascal Triangle, turn it into a vector and analyze the remainder of the division, but when I run the script, it returns the message `Error in ptest(2) : could not find function "ptest"`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Seems like you haven't run the `ptest` function definition before you ran `ptest(2)`.

Comment: You also have a few errors. You need `if(x%%h == 0)` with `==`, not `=`. And your `for` loop `}` ends *before* the `if` statement, but it seems like it should end after the `else{}`.